# macro definition that would differentiate static and non static function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-macros

Suppose I have two functions, one static and one non static as follows,

```
#define PRINT_INFO(__FUNCTION__,...) cout<<__FUNCTION__<<__VA_ARGS__
void static fun1();
void fun2();

fun1(){
PRINT_INFO(__FUNCTION__,this)
}

fun2(){
PRINT_INFO(__FUNCTION__,this)
}
```

The fun1()'s PRINT_INFO would throw error as 'this' cannot be used in a static function. Is there any way I could achieve the above, that is, if the function is non-static then pass 'this', if it is static then pass nothing(or some dummy string).

Rephrasing my question: I want to pass 'this' if the function is static and pass nothing if the function is non static. But I dont want to check all the functions in my code and then add 'this' to only non-statics. 
Can I dynamically know if a function is static or not?

Comment: pass NULL instead of this?

Comment: Why did you put `this` in the macro's arguments when inside a `static` function?

Comment: maybe you could try playing with C++11 traits: http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer or http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_pointer

Comment: @5gon12eder I rephrased my question..

Comment: But I still don't understand it.  You do type all those macro invocations yourself, don't you?  Or do you have some magic facility that inserted them into every function?

Comment: Also: The variadric macro parameters won't do what you probably expect.  `PRINT_INFO(__FUNCTION__, this, 3, 0.4, "bananas")` will not output `funX 0x12345 3 0.4 bananas` (not even without the spaces).  And it is `__VA_ARGS__`  (or is the misspelling a Visual Studio “feature”?).  I think your problem was better solved using template meta-programming.

Comment: @5gon12eder: I do have the magic facility to insert the macro call within functions.(basically a python script that inserts them into functions). Since the code base is very large, it becomes difficult to find if the function is static or not in the python pre-parser. So if I could dynamically find this info, then I could have the macro defined to use the dynamic info.

Comment: Then it would probably be easiest to teach the script to recognize the `static` keyword.  It sounds comparatively simple in contrast to parsing C++ in order to tell where a function begins.  But of course I don't know how your code is organized.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Yeah, but the problem is .h files would have the static definition and .class would have the implementation. I would have to  refer to both to find whether a function is static or not. A little teedious it is! If C++ has some form of reflection way to look into function nature, it would have helped.

Comment: The preprocessor has no understanding of code, it operates on tokens only. This is insufficient to understand whether the (yet to be) function it operates "within" is static or not. The compiler is "too late", it cannot deal with `this` even if it is unevaluated.